# CYYMMDD format in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, formatdatetime

I am trying to compare two dataframe date columns.

In the first dataframe

```
Name   DOB
Alex   25071986
Jane   14122002
Sujan  28021999
```

The DOB in `ddmmyyyy` format.

In the other dataframe

```
Name   DOB
Alex   0250786
Jane   1141202
Sujan  0280299
```

The DOB is in `cddmmyy` format.
Here c represnts the century elapse from 1900. So for 1986 it is 0, for 2002 it is 1 and so on...

What I have done so far is:

```
1) abc <- lubridate::mdy(df1[,DOB])
```

which shows `abc` in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
2) a <- strftime(abc, format = "%C%d%m%y")
```

which gives me `CCDDMMYY` for example for `2016-12-11` it gives `20111216`

Which is not what I need, I need it to be `1111216` (`CDDMMYY`).

Can someone help?

Comment: there may be an easier way with some other packages, but have you tried converting the latter date to `as.character` and then removing the leading digits? Then converting to the same date format as the former?

Comment: Maybe `sprintf("%d%s", lubridate::year(abc) %/% 100 - 19, strftime(abc, format = "%d%m%y"))`.

Comment: @nycrefugee I followed step 1 as I need to standardize the date to something that R understands and then convert it to other format I need it step two.If there is any other method by which I can compare ddmmyyyy to cdmmyy I will be happy to try.

Comment: @Rui Barradas I will give it a try.

Comment: @Rui Barradas I have posted your comment as answer, please let me know the logic behind year(abc) %% 100 -19, it should give you 16 if year is 1916 , so how are you using it further?

Comment: It's not `%%` the remainder, it's `%/%` the integer division. So `1916 %/% 100` equals `19` and then subtract `19` since you want to start at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Rui Barradas,

```
sprintf("%d%s", lubridate::year(abc) %/% 100 - 19, strftime(abc, format = "%d%m%y"))
```

did the job for me.